# Android - ListView dynamic Buttons for each row calling dynamic listeners

Tags: android, listview, button

I'm new to android, i've spent the last 2 days trying previous examples and online solutions but I just can't seem to get my head around it :(

I'm able to display a list view, parse some json from online and store a book title, book description and book ID and display this data in the listview. I want to be able to put a 'download' button in each row for the ListView, each button will correspond to its book ID on Click() and the action listener will download the book by appending that ID to a url.
e.g www.books.com/download_book1    or /download_book2....

Here is my code. Catalogue.java class

```
public class Catalogue extends ListActivity {

private JSONObject json;
private ListView lv;

private ArrayList<Integer> alKey = new ArrayList<Integer>();

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //icicle
            setContentView(R.layout.shelflist);
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


....
try{

                JSONArray entries = json.getJSONArray("entries");

                for(int i=0;i<entries.length();i++){                        
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                    JSONObject e = entries.getJSONObject(i);

                    alKey.add(e.getInt("key")); 
                    map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                    map.put("title", "Title:" + e.getString("title"));
                    map.put("description", "Description: " +  e.getString("description"));
                    mylist.add(map);


                }       
            }catch(JSONException e)        {
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.shelfrow, 
                            new String[] { "title", "description" }, 
                            new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

            setListAdapter(adapter);

                    lv = getListView();
                    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

.....

This is as far as I get. I don't know how to add 1 button per row in the List and assign an action listener to each button.
I also have a shelfrow.xml file (textView, textView for item_title and item_subtitle) and a shelflist.xml file (ListView). 
I have a shelf.xml file with

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically you need to learn the concept of [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html).

Here's the short story: picture an object that holds the data to be displayed inside a list, along with the way to display each line individually. That's your ListAdapter. Now take each individual line: it's a book with a title and an OnClickListener. It's rendered inside a View with a TextView (for the title) and a Button (for the OnClickListener). All you need to do is give one View to the adapter that will be used for each line, and a List of the books you want to be inside the list.

Here's some sample code. I hope it clears things up a bit

```
private class MyItemModel{ //that's our book
    String title; // the book's title
            String description;
            long id;
    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener(){ // the book's action
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // the default action for all lines
            doSomethingWithTheBookTitleOrUniqueId(this);
        }
    };
}

private class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    View renderer;
    List<MyItemModel> items;

            // call this one and pass it layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item)
    public MyListAdapter(View renderer) {
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }

            // whenever you need to set the list of items just use this method.
            // call it when you have the data ready and want to display it
    public void setModel(List<MyItemModel> items){
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items!=null?items.size():0;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items!=null?items.get(position):null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return items!=null?items.get(position).id:-1;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = renderer;
        }
        MyItemModel item = items.get(position);
             // replace those R.ids by the ones inside your custom list_item layout.
        TextView label = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        label.setText(item.label);
        Button button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(item.listener);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

In order to pass the List, instead of putting the data inside your list of hashmaps you can do this for instance (be careful, I also updated the MyItemModel and MyListAdapter to your need, added the id and description properties):

```
List<MyItemModel> myListModel = new ArrayList<MyItemModel>();
try{
    JSONArray entries = json.getJSONArray("entries");
    for(int i=0;i<entries.length();i++){                        
        MyItemModel item = new MyItemModel();    
        JSONObject e = entries.getJSONObject(i);
        alKey.add(e.getInt("key")); 
        item.id = i;
        item.title = e.getString("title");
        item.description = e.getString("description");
        // you can change the button action at this point: 
        // item.onClickListener = new OnClickListener(){...};
        myListModel.add(item);
    }

}catch(JSONException e)        {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
ListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.shelfrow, this));
adapter.setModel(myListModel);
setListAdapter(adapter);
lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I kind of get what you are saying in the sort story but i'm still having trouble coding it all properly

Comment: I'm working on changing ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter to MyListAdapter

Comment: in my activity (shelf class) how do I pass my hashmap data (title and description) into the my adapter?

Comment: two possibilities: 1) you can create a List<MyItemModel> from your hashmap (or directly from the JSONArray) and when it's done you call setModel() on the adapter, or 2) you can change the MyListAdapter so that it uses directly your List<HashMap<String, Object>>... will edit the answer, looks like you need to get some more practice with java :)

Comment: thanks. this is a lot clearer to me now. I've added some setter/getters into the ListItemModel class. I'm getting an error on the line: MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(getLayout.Inflater().inflate(R.layout.shelf) which is The method inflate(int, ViewGroup) in the type LayoutInflater is not applicable for the arguments 
 (int)

Comment: aye, my mistake - what the layout inflater does is take an xml description, build a View with it, and adds it as a child to another view. In that case it's probably the Activity/ListActivity itself, or "this".

Comment: also myListModel.add(map); - doesn't make sense to me because you aren't using map anymore and myListModel is an arraylist of the class type MyItemModel... shouldn't it be .add(item)?

Comment: good call, that one was a typo. It's of course supposed to be "item" instead of "map". Get some more exercise with Java, do some more tutorials and you'll figure out all these answers by yourself soon :)

Comment: i can't thank you enough for your help. Your help has been fantastic. I am thinking that because I need to be creating a new instance of View for each row in MyListAdapter..I need to somehow do View v = new View (based on shelfrow.xml) and pass that into             MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(v);

Comment: Actually you shouldn't create a new View for each row. The ListView handles it under the hood, it uses only one view (the one in the adapter's getView method), paints it on the screen for each line and recycles it, which saves a ton of memory! But you're right in that you still need to somehow create this recycled view at the start and pass it to the adapter. In my example, I created it with the LayoutInflater.

Comment: perhaps..LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shelfrow, null);

Comment: i have it all working now. Took me longer than I should but got there in the end. Thank you soooo much for the walkthrough. You've helped me out a LOT!

Comment: hmm i thought i had it al working right. But i'm not able to to display more than 1 item in the list at a time. Still stuck with MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.shelfrow, this));

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own class extending ArrayAdapter that will hold your list and set onClickListener to the Button in each row.

But in getView method of your ArrayAdapter you have to create a new view every time.

for example - row layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:background="#FFF"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="2dp"
              android:layout_height="110dp">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_title"
              android:background="#FFF"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="40dp"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/download_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Download"
            android:layout_height="35dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and getView method in ArrayAdapter

```
private List<Map<String, String>> jsonMapList;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    // here you set textview values (title and description)
    // TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);
    // title.setText('bla');

    // and set OnClickListener
    Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.download_button);                
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            downloadFile(getUrl(position));
        }
    });

    return v;
}

// method that downloads file
private void downloadFile(String url) {}

// get url from your list by index
private String getUrl(int index) {
    return jsonMapList.get(index).get("url");
}
```

Usage of Map is unnecessary, you could use any object you prefer.

In activity class

```
    CustomAdapter listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, jsonMapList);
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);
```